# Python List Comprehension: How do I manipulate text from a file

Tags: python, file, list-comprehension

I have a file called `nbatams.txt` that includes the following contents

```
Bucks 41

Raptors 35

Celtics 32

Heat 32

Pacers 31

76ers 31

Nets 21

Magic 21
```

I am trying to read parts of the file with list comprehension, but I seem to be doing something wrong.

For example, I would like to display all the teams with more than 30 wins and the team names with more than 5 letters.

I figured out that I could do this

```
file_contents = [line.strip() for line in open("nbateams.txt", "r")]
for team in file_contents:
    name, wins = team.split()
    print("The", name, "have won", wins)
```

To get the list of teams with wins, but I tried

```
five_letters = [teams for teams in file_contents if len(team_name) < 5] 
print(five_letters)
```

and that is not right at all. I am just getting an empty list. I would really appreciate some assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are checking the length of the entire line in your list comprehension.

Try this instead:

```py
five_letters = [line.split()[0] for line in file_contents if len(line.split()[0]) < 5]
```

This should allow you to check the length only of the single team name, e then add it to your list.

Comment: Thank you! If I may ask, what do the [0] and [1] mean?

Comment: That syntax is used to access the single element of a list. Python lists are zero indexed, so the first element belongs to index 0, the second to 1 and so on...